# Historical data on forests and land use in the United Kingdom

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uk, land

**EDIT: I have posted this question to the [history.SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/50952/14615) after a discussion on that site's meta.**

Are there any sources of historical land use/land cover data for the United Kingdom? I'm specifically interested in datasets that, for each point/area in the UK (ideally, at as a high a resolution as possible), list whether the land was forest, urban, agricultural/cultivated, etc. for the time period 1800-1900.

There are modern versions of these data, e.g. the [Corine land cover data](https://catalogue.ceh.ac.uk/documents/32533dd6-7c1b-43e1-b892-e80d61a5ea1d), which have been addressed in [other](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/193344/126188) [questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/181659/126188), but nothing historical.

The [Ordnance Surveys](https://maps.nls.uk/os/6inch-england-and-wales/) supposedly include some data like this for the years 1842 onward, but actually looking at the [list of years in which each county was mapped](https://maps.nls.uk/os/county-series/dates-england-and-wales.html) shows that the actual data is mostly much later.
https://maps.nls.uk/os/6inch-england-and-wales/

Comment: I flagged this question for a move to the history.SE, but since the flag received no response (it's still pending, in fact) I went ahead and posted the question there.